# TomEE : Allocate exception for servlet jersey-serlvet

Tags: java, servlets, apache-tomee

I am getting the below exception while calling the rest webservice in Tomee 1.7.2.

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet JerseyServlet
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [com] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension$2.stepInto(CDIExtension.java:290)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.diveIntoJNDIContext(CDIExtension.java:267)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.lookupJerseyConfigJNDIContext(CDIExtension.java:287)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIExtension.getInitializedExtension(CDIExtension.java:175)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactory.<init>(CDIComponentProviderFactory.java:92)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.initialize(CDIComponentProviderFactoryInitializer.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:572)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:312)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have defined the servlet in my web.xml as

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.edifixio.osrd.web.mogui.restfulws</param-value>
    </init-param>
   <!--  <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param> -->
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Note: It works well in **weblogic** server and if I ***remove the servlet declaration in web.xml*** it works well in TomEE also.

Comment: The exception is thrown from the init()-Methode of your servlet.
It doesn't have anything to do with the web.xml itself.

Comment: Yes. But how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made this to work by

1)
  Removing `jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar` from `common.loader` of `[TomEE_HOME]/conf/catalina.properties` file and

2)Added

```
 openejb.api.javax.ws.rs.Path.validation=false
 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true
```

to  `[TomEE_HOME]\conf\system.properties`

3) Removed `jersey-core-1.17.1`,`jersey-json-1.17.1`,`jersey-server-1.17.1` and `jersey-servlet-1.17.1` from `[TomEE_HOME]/lib`

I have shared the sample project in github.

Repository location: `https://github.com/UnknownU/TomeeRestfulWs.git`